# Check a data exist or not in file by checking 2 by 2 line using VBScript

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript

I have a file like this : 7G8h6Tghstwt6Y.y8 .
Then, I have a string data like this : "2w" & "fr" & "7G"
I am going to check whether my string data exist in the file or not.

```
filepath = "C:\Users\Desktop\TS.txt"
substrToFind = "2w" & "fr" & "6J"

For i = 1 To Len(tmpStr) Step 2
    If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) <= 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "0:"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "1"
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54745001/692942) not already help? I'm not sure how you've got where you are from that suggestion. What is the point of `"2w" & "fr" & "6J"`, its just `"2wfr6J"`? The string concatenation isn't necessary. Also, what is `tmpStr`?

Comment: No. It's not :(. Ya. the point look like this 2w fr 67

Comment: Well it should of because that answer is the right approach, breaking the string down using `Mid()` and then comparing it to the values from the source array. I don't think this warrants another question, please don't post duplicate questions. @Ansgar pretty much wrote the entire code for you *(against my better judgement)*. If you don't understand how to take that advice and build a solution then no amount of help here is going to help, suggest you find a good VBScript tutorial and learn the basics or hire a programmer to do it for you.